Resleeving a small engine?
Can you guys please help me settle a debate with a mechanic friend of mine? He claims that it is possible to keep a small Honda or similar engine running literally for tens of thousands of hours by rebuilding the original block with a dry sleeve. I could see a couple of rebuilds, but isn’t there a limit to how many times an engine can be resleeved? Something doesn’t sound right about a small engine with 20,000+ hours on the original block.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

A block, in and of itself, won't usually wear out under normal use. The wear comes at the contact points within the engine (ie: crankshaft/rod journal bearings; rings on cylinder walls; pistons against cylinder walls; cylinder walls contacting rings/pistons). The block is the basis for keeping things together. If done correctly, you can re-sleeve a block multiple times without issues, running the engine between an overhaul many thousands of hours. Also, just because the rings/bearings are worn out, doesn't mean you need to sleeve the block. If maintenance is kept up (ie: oil changes, air/oil filter changes) with the small engine, a simple ring/bearing rebuild can be done and again you'd be able to run it for a long period before the next go around. If an engine can be sleeved/re-sleeved, it is certainly possible for it to run as many hours as you're stating.
The real question becomes, is rebuilding an engine in this manner fiscally feasible? If it costs more money to rebuild an engine then it does to replace it (figure in labor hours, parts, and machining if having it done somewhere), it doesn't make sense to rebuild. You mentioned a Honda engine, which aren't cheap to begin with. They might be a separate case. Many small engines today are produced in China and come very cheap and plentiful, which makes them ripe for replacement versus rebuild.

Thank you for your reply. I was really incredulous of the idea that somebody could essentially keep what is a lawnmower, engine, running as long as an industrial diesel, just by replacing the parts and the sleeve. What separates this from two-stroke engines the crank cases on two-stroke engines seem to usually crack after a couple of rebuilds.
